# Gradle to much long time to package (java) (IDEA)

Tags: gradle, package

I have a some problem with Gradle. when I made the application gradle build package fast enough. After some time it was build project y 3-4 minutes and more.

I tried invalidate the cache, reset idea but to no avail.
The i decided **to change dependency of driver for my database** and build of my project accelerated again.

Comment: I find simple way. Before start your application use update button on Gradle tab in idea